# Inline equation with set introduces symbols rather than numbers

Tags: math-mode, equations

Can someone tell me what is going on here?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

An inline equation $\cal{A}\subseteq \{0,\dots,n\}\times \{0,\dots,m\}$
with funny characters instead of numbers.

\end{document}
```

Instead of `0`, `n` and `m`, a backslash, an updownarrow and another symbol are typeset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax: the old editions of the LaTeX manual specified that the font change had to be typed

```
{\cal A}
```

rather than

```
\cal{A}
```

because `\cal` had a behavior quite similar to `\it` or `\bf`. However, these commands have been deprecated since the release of LaTeX2e in 1994.

The two letter font changing commands (`\it`, `\bf` and so on) and `\cal` have been replaced by clearer commands with an argument, distinguishing between "text" and "math":

- `{\bf X}` → `\textbf{X}` or `\mathbf{X}`
- `{\it X}` → `\textit{X}` or `\mathit{X}`
- ...
- `{\cal X}` → `\mathcal{X}`

However, for backward compatibility, the old commands are still available (the two letter ones might not be, though, for instance in the `memoir` class).

Since `\cal` is a font switching command similar to `\it`, it influences *all* the formula; for technical reasons, its result is not readily predictable when non uppercase letters are involved.

***Never use `\cal`***, it has been obsolete and deprecated for almost twenty years.

Comment: @lenz: A lot of the *old* font commands are switches rather than macros. We tend to see many newcommers write e.g. `\Large{text}` ...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; despite having used (xela)tex for quite some time now, I don't really overlook the layers of commands from different eras. Often, I'm simply led by the autocompletion suggestions of my editor (not in the case of `\cal` though, that was my own vague guess from the back of my head).

Comment: @daleif: Yes, sure, you can't blame them for that :-p